# SAML configuration in django allauth is overwriting user named 'user'

Tags: django-allauth

I am using `SAML` provider.

Logging in creates a Django user named 'user' and social account.

All the data ends up in the "extra data" field.

I want it to create. New user when user logs in.

Here is my environment:

```
Django==4.2.7; python_version >= '3.8'
django-allauth==0.58.2
python3-saml==1.16.0
```

Here is my configuration `JSON`.

```
{"idp": {"name": "example IdP", "slo_url": "https://wac.example.com/sso_cond2fa_2023/SingleLogoutService", "sso_url": "https://wac.example.com/sso_cond2fa_2023/SingleSignOnService", "x509cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----XXXXX-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "entity_id": "urn:dev-123.us.auth0.com"}, "advanced": {"strict": false}, "attribute_mapping": {"uid": "http://schemas.auth0.com/clientID", "email": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "surname": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", "firstname": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", "email_verified": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"}}
```

More info, here is screenshot of the results:

[image: screenshot]

I did check the `SAML` Tracker and I do see that extra data in there too. Anyway I can force it to use those values to populate the Admin User so it is unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attribute_mapping` section to pick up data from `extra_data` and save them in fields of `user`/`socialaccount`:

```json
"attribute_mapping": {
    "email": "mail",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "uid": "uid",
    "username": "uid"
}
```